# jQuery queue execution misunderstanding

Tags: jquery, queue

I am trying to make a read-more/hide text effect on a div with content in a site I'm building. I have made the effects I wish to use and I have tried them one by one in console which works as it should, but when I use them with a queue, something just messes up and the effects go out of order.

Here's a link to the demo page:
[Demo Link](http://casaazul.zebradm.mx/inicio.php)

So, in order to test the demo, you have to click on the '-' button under the 'Leer mas...' tooltip.

The opening effect works fine, and I want to do exactly the same effect for closing, just inverted. I tested it in console with the following commands...

```
$('#texto p').queue(function() { $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000); $(this).dequeue(); });    
$('#texto').queue(function() { $(this).animate({ height: '1px' }, 1000); $(this).dequeue(); });
$('#texto p').queue(function() { $(this).hide(0); $(this).dequeue(); } );
$('#texto').queue(function() { $(this).css('height','auto'); $(this).dequeue(); });
$('#texto').queue(function() { $(this).animate({ width: '-=350px' }, 600); $(this).dequeue(); });
$('.content').queue(function() { $(this).animate({ width: '-=350px' }, 600); $(this).dequeue(); });
$('#leer_mas').queue(function() { $(this).fadeIn(500); $(this).dequeue(); }); 

$(this).removeClass('extendido');
```

The order is basically the following:

1. I turn the paragraphs transparent.
2. I reduce the paragraphs' parent div's height to 1 to hide the paragraph with overflow.
3. I then hide the paragraphs in order to be able to use the show functionality.
4. Then I remove the 1px height to leave the parent div usable with the show functionality.
5. Then I reduce the parent's with 350px.
6. I do the same with the main div.
7. I show the 'Leer mas...' span.
8. I remove the .extendido class.

When I do it step by step in console it works perfectly but I think I'm doing something wrong with the queue. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: If possible, can post `html` , `css` , `$(this)` element of `$(this).removeClass('extendido');` ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your actions are attached to different elements: `#texto p`, `#texto`, `.content`, and `#leer_mas`. Each one has its own queue, and they run in parallel. So steps 1 and 2 happen at the same time, not sequentially. If you want all the steps to run sequentially, use the `complete:` option to `.animate`, giving it the function for the next step in the chain.

Instead of

```
$('#texto p').queue(function() { $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000); $(this).dequeue(); });
```

try:

```
$(document).queue(function() { $('#texto p').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000); $(this).dequeue(); });
```

and similar changes for all the other animations.

Comment: Is there a way to put them in the same queue? Because as far as I know until now the queue is based on the object in question, but I've also seen queue naming. How does that work?

Also, why does it do the opening effect correctly?

Comment: I did that but it keeps doing the same thing. I queued every step to document. You can check the original link, its code is updated.

Comment: I think the problem is that `.animate` uses the element's queue automatically, so that it doesn't block the UI. So putting animation inside a queue on another object is ineffective. You should use the `complete` option of `.animate` to chain these animations.

Comment: Hmm, it's not that simple -- some of your queued actions aren't `.animate`. I'm out of ideas, maybe someone else has an answer.

Comment: @Barmar Can possibly return `$(element).promise()` , `$(element).promise().done(fn)` to "non-promise" elements / objects to maintain chaining ? See post , Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 That does look promising, I wasn't aware of that method. Perhaps you should write an answer that shows how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: @Barmar See post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25842176/2801559); note `fn4` where `$('#texto').css('height', 'auto')` chained to , returning `promise().done(dq)`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note, Not certain about `$(this)` element of `$(this).removeClass('extendido');` ? `.extendido` class attached to `.content` element at piece below

Try

```
function fn1() {
    return $('#texto p').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000, dq)
};

function fn2() {
    return $('#texto').animate({
        height: '1px'
    }, 1000, dq)
};

function fn3() {
    return $('#texto p').hide(0, dq);
};

function fn4() {
    return $('#texto').css('height', 'auto')
      .promise().done(dq);
};

function fn5() {
    return $('#texto').animate({
        width: '-=350px'
    }, 600, dq)
};

function fn6() {
    return $('.content').animate({
        width: '-=350px'
    }, 600, dq)
};

function fn7() {
    return $('#leer_mas').fadeIn(500, function () {
        $(".content").removeClass("extendido")
    })
};

$.queue($(".content")[0], "steps", [fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6, fn7]);

var dq = function () {
    return $.dequeue($(".content")[0], "steps")
};

dq();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8ay5s3zg/

Comment: The thread is kind of old now, but isn't this a little over complicated? I ended up playing with CSS overflow and I think it's easier and less code in the end. I haven't had the chance to update the answer.